# How to simplify my array codes

Tags: php, database, arrays

I am trying to assign my `db` returned results to an array

I have

```
$results = Db::get('get_items', array('id' =>$id));

$Info['items'][1]['title'] = $results[0]['Name'];
$Info['items'][1]['name'] = $results[0]['Filename'];
$Info['items'][1]['type'] = $results[0]['Type];
```

The DB only returns 1 row of data.

I need my `$info` looks like the following

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title test
                    [filename] => test.xml
                    [type] => company
                )

        )

    [mis] => data
)
```

I was wondering if there are a better way to assign the value to `$info` than just `hardcoded` them all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried `print_r($results);` ? what did you get?

Comment: I did get what I need as an output, but I want to see if I can make the codes prettier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array to describe the key mappings:

```
$map = array('Name' => 'title',
             'Filename' => 'name',
             'Type' => 'type');

foreach ($results[0] as $key => $value) {
    $Info['items'][1][$map[$key]] = $value;
}
```

Any time you want to perform some kind of one-to-one translation, you should immediately think of using an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query so you are getting the fields AS the field name you want.  I don't know what your DB class does, but with mySQL you can do

```
SELECT `Filename` as `name` FROM table;
```

Then you can do:

```
$Info['items'][1] = $results[0];
```